# SVN copy only certain directories and subdirectories to a branch

Tags: svn

I have the following directory structure in trunk:

```
trunk
      - dir1
      - dir2
          -subdir1
          -subdir2
```

I want to copy dir2/subdir2 to my https://mynewbranchurl

If I do `svn cp ./dir2/subdir2 https://mynewbranchurl` I see subdir2 directly under mynewbranch. What should I do to get dir2/subdir2/contents in mynewbranch?

I do not want to manually create dir2 in mynewbranch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **--parents** option for the copy command:

```
svn cp --parents ./dir2/subdir2 http://repourl/branches/my_new_branch/dir2/subdir2
```

In this way Subversion creates all intermediate directories (I am not sure if you need subdir2, please test it)

Answer (score 1):

So let's say that http://mysvn.com/repos/branches already exists, and after the copy you want `trunk/dir2/subdir2` to be located at http://mysvn.com/repos/branches/my_new_branch, such that `trunk/dir2/subdir2/file.txt` is located at http://mysvn.com/repos/branches/my_new_branch/file.txt.  Just do this:

`svn cp ./dir2/subdir2 http://mysvn.com/repos/branches/my_new_branch`

Make sure that `my_new_branch` does not exist before the copy operation.  If it does exist, it will place dir2 inside of the existing folder.  I think that might be what's giving you grief.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not want the contents directly under mynewbranch. My question is I want to see mynewbranch/dir2/subdir1/contents not mynewbranch/contents

Comment: So you want dir2, subdir2, and subdir2/contents, but you don't want dir2/contents (if there are any non-directory contents), nor do you want subdir1 nor subdir1/contents?